# Documentation - Is there a list of available properties for deployment manager resources?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I'm trying to GCP create deployment manager templates for our architecture.

For example, while creating a sql instance, this is what I have in my yaml file:

```
- name: carlosinstance
  type: gcp-types/sqladmin-v1beta4:instances
  properties:
    region: us-europe-west1
    settings:
      tier: db-n1-standard-1
```

I keep running into issues like this one:

```
- code: RESOURCE_ERROR
  location: /deployments/foo3/resources/carlosinstance
  message: '{"ResourceType":"gcp-types/sqladmin-v1beta4:instances","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"errors":[{"domain":"global","location":"","locationType":"other","message":"Unknown field name: zone","reason":"invalid"}],"message":"Unknown field name: zone","statusMessage":"Bad Request","requestPath":"https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/demo-project1/instances/carlosinstance","httpMethod":"PUT"}}'
```

I've run `gcloud deployment-manager type list` successfully to see a full list of available types, but i can't find complete documentation on what properties are available or required for each type.

Specifically I'm looking for `gcp-types/sqladmin-v1beta4:instances` and `appengine.v1.version` but would love to find a comprehensive list.

All I can find in the GCP documentation is for the REST api: `https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types`

Answer (score 0):

In your original question, you posted this link:

https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types

If we look at that page, we see that there are links to `further documentation` for each of the resource types.  These appear to describe all the available options.  For example, for `appengine.v1.version` we are taken to:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions

which seems to be quite comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks for your response Kolban.
I was originally driven off these because they're for the REST api, but after your response I tried to map them to the yaml file in the way that you would expect and it worked.

Thanks.